# why my icon colors or icons does not change when I switch theme in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-theme, android-icons

There is a screen in my application that I use to change the theme. There are three options named the same as light theme, dark theme and system. When you click on these options, the theme of the app changes, but the color of the icons does not change. However, I have two types of drawable files, dark and light, my codes are as follows

**ThemeScreen**

```
  val isSystemDarkTheme = isSystemInDarkTheme()

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            SelectableTitleWithIcon(
                title = stringResource(id = R.string.karanlik),
                shouldShowImage = state.selectedThemeType == ThemeType.DarkTheme,
                onClick = {
                    onChangeThemeType(ThemeType.DarkTheme)
                    saveThemeChoose(ThemeType.DarkTheme)
                    saveDarkTheme(true)
                })
            CustomDivider(startPadding = 15.dp, endPadding = 15.dp)
            SelectableTitleWithIcon(
                title = stringResource(id = R.string.aydinlik),
                shouldShowImage = state.selectedThemeType == ThemeType.LightTheme,
                onClick = {
                    onChangeThemeType(ThemeType.LightTheme)
                    saveThemeChoose(ThemeType.LightTheme)
                    saveDarkTheme(false)
                })
            CustomDivider(startPadding = 15.dp, endPadding = 15.dp)
            SelectableTitleWithIcon(
                title = stringResource(id = R.string.sistem_ile_ayni),
                shouldShowImage = state.selectedThemeType == ThemeType.SystemTheme,
                onClick = {
                    onChangeThemeType(ThemeType.SystemTheme)
                    saveThemeChoose(ThemeType.SystemTheme)
                    if (isSystemDarkTheme) saveDarkTheme(true) else saveDarkTheme(false)
                })
            CustomDivider(startPadding = 15.dp, endPadding = 15.dp)
        }
    }
```

**ThemeScreenViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class ThemeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val dataStoreUtil: DataStoreUtil,
    private val dataStoreHelper: PreferenceDataStoreHelper
) : ViewModel() {


    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(ThemeScreenState())
    val state: StateFlow<ThemeScreenState> = _state.asStateFlow()

   
    fun onChangeThemeType(themeType: ThemeType){
        _state.update {
            it.copy(
                selectedThemeType = themeType
            )
        }
    }
    fun saveThemeChoose(themeType: ThemeType) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dataStoreHelper.putPreference(PreferenceDataStoreConstants.THEME_CHOOSE, themeType.name)
        }
    }

    fun saveDarkTheme(isDarkTheme: Boolean) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dataStoreUtil.saveTheme(isDarkTheme)
        }
    }

}


sealed class ThemeType(val name: String) {
    object DarkTheme : ThemeType("dark_theme")
    object LightTheme : ThemeType("light_theme")
    object SystemTheme : ThemeType("system_theme")
    object Default : ThemeType("default")

    companion object {
        fun fromName(name: String): ThemeType {
            return when (name) {
                DarkTheme.name -> DarkTheme
                LightTheme.name -> LightTheme
                SystemTheme.name -> SystemTheme
                Default.name -> Default
                else -> SystemTheme
            }
        }
    }
}

data class ThemeScreenState(
    val selectedThemeType: ThemeType = ThemeType.Default
)
```

**MainActivity**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
  private lateinit var dataStoreUtil: DataStoreUtil

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        dataStoreUtil = DataStoreUtil(applicationContext)


        val systemTheme = when (resources.configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> { true }
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> { false }
            else -> { false }
        }

        setContent {
            val theme = dataStoreUtil.getTheme(systemTheme).collectAsState(initial = systemTheme)
            println("theme->"+theme.value)
            AppTheme(darkTheme = theme.value) {
             ...
```

**AppTheme**

```
private val DarkColors = darkColors(
    background = md_theme_dark_background,
    surface = md_theme_dark_surface,
    primary = md_theme_dark_primary,
    primaryVariant = md_theme_dark_primary_variant,
    onPrimary = md_theme_dark_onPrimaryContainer,
    secondary = md_theme_dark_primary,
    onSecondary = md_theme_dark_onPrimaryContainer,
    secondaryVariant = md_theme_dark_secondaryContainer,
)

private val LightColors = lightColors(
    background = md_theme_light_background,
    surface = md_theme_light_surface,
    primary = md_theme_light_primary,
    primaryVariant = md_theme_light_primary_variant,
    onPrimary = md_theme_light_onPrimaryContainer,
    secondary = md_theme_light_primary,
    onSecondary = md_theme_light_onPrimaryContainer,
    secondaryVariant = md_theme_light_primary_variant,
)


@Composable
fun AppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {

    val colors = if (darkTheme) DarkColors else LightColors

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = MontSerratTypography(colors),
        content = content,
    )
}
```

[image: enter code here]

hear is the screenshot

**dark mode**

[image]

**light mode**

[image]

theme.value writes correct in logcat when I change the theme in ThemeScreen for example I choose DarkTheme it print true or when I choose light theme it print false. I also added night icons and light icons as you can see below image Even though I did everything I couldn't do it. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I think you should check for darkTheme and change your ```iconTint``` as per theme change

Comment: isn't there another way? because it may be difficult to do this for all icons.

Comment: You can use your theme color as ```iconTint``` so it would change as per dark or light mode

Comment: I can do your suggestion but there are a lot of icons and it will probably increase in the future. Isn't it difficult to add tint while adding the icon like this every time? Shouldn't it work the way I do anyway? I mean that.

Comment: You can make your own ```Composable``` function where you can manage it easily.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is here. These are just temporary solutions, that is, the color of the icons does not only consist of uniform colors such as black and white, some of them have colors such as orange and blue etc. I mean, I do not understand how I can do this with a single composable function, as you said?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255375/discussion-between-newpartizal-and-chirag-thummar).

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are only changing the `colors` of your `MaterialTheme` when theme changes, which cannot affect the source of drawables that will be used (`drawable` or `drawable-night`). To change that, you have to set the night mode using [`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegate#setDefaultNightMode(int)). You can do that in your `MainActivity` like this:

```kotlin
setContent {
    val theme = dataStoreUtil.getTheme(systemTheme).collectAsState(initial = systemTheme)
    
    LaunchedEffect(theme) {
        snapshotFlow { theme.value }.collect { dark ->
            val mode = when {
                dark -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
                else -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
            }
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(mode)
        }
    }

    AppTheme(darkTheme = theme.value) {}
}
```

Comment: Jan is your activity extending `AppCompatActivity`?